# Cloning a hard disk or creating a backup

Tags: hard-drive, backup, system-installation

I am changing my hard disk because in Ubuntu it shows "Disk Failure is Imminent". Which option is better:

- Should I clone my hard disk with new one or
- Should I create a backup using Ubuntu Backup and then restore it to new hard disk?

How much time each will take for 500 GB hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which one is better, but I would go for a bitwise clone of the hard-drive using either `dd`, `ddrescue` or `clonezilla`. These utilities ignore the file-system and just copy the sectors. Clonezilla in particular is space efficient: by default it copies only used sectors *and* compresses the backup image (see [Save 1st disk (sda) as an image on 2nd disk (sdb)](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) tutorial).

The other solution would be to use a file-system-level utility like `rsync` or `grsync`. This could work reasonably well, too, especially if the drive hasn't yet developed bad or corrupted sectors. (If it has, however, see `ddrescue`.)

Whatever you do, though, **stop** using the dying drive now. Well, that is, if you put any value on your data.

See also:

- [How to clone to a smaller harddisk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409204/how-to-clone-to-a-smaller-harddisk)

Comment: one more suggestion.i am creating backup on my hard disk.after that i copy it onto the DVD.will it create any problem  ??

Comment: Why would you do that? How big is your hard-drive? Is it small enough to fit a DVD?

Comment: No my hard disk is 500GB.

Comment: is there any compression during Backup ?? How will i restore it.please guideline a little.