# Can I copy a complete drive using Ubuntu?

Tags: drive, copy

I am new to Ubuntu.  As for Windows, can I copy or clone an entire drive,  including the operating system, when using Ubuntu 18.04?

Regards,

Jerin

Comment: You can use [https://clonezilla.org/](https://clonezilla.org/) to clone a drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) and [What is the best way to clone a disk?](https://askubuntu.com/q/616820/)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to clone an disk.

You can use software like clonezilla, or copy an entire disk to a file / drive with `dd`.

Please note that `dd` is commonly referred to as disk destroyer because people make typos and delete their data with it.

Personally I would use a tool like clonezilla to backup a drive, and `dd` to copy 1 drive to another.

Comment: yeah try clonezilla, but beware i have never used it and i do not know if your cloned windows os drive will still run on another drive/system afterwards.

Comment: Windows will probably run, but say it is not genuine any more.