# Proper Way to Produce Image of Truncated GPT Drive

Tags: partitioning, gpt, disk-image, compression, gdisk

[Another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189682/how-to-truncate-a-disk-image-file-of-unused-space-without-corrupting-gpt-partiti) addresses a scenario where `truncate` damages an image of a GPT drive. If I understand correctly, the advice there is to use `gdisk` to repair the damage. I would rather not cause the damage in the first place.

I have a Windows 10 installation [on a 256GB USB GPT drive](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2023/08/22/wtg-update/). I've used a Windows partitioner (MiniTool Partition Wizard) to squeeze the partitions down to a size that will fit onto a 128GB drive. This is what I want to image.

I can use Gnome Disks to create a 256GB raw image. But, as above, using `truncate` to reduce that to 128GB - to get rid of ~128GB of unallocated space at the end - will apparently damage the GPT partitioning.

As far as I can tell `gdisk` is looking for partitions to work with. I could convert the 128GB unallocated space into a partition, and then use `gdisk` to delete it - but won't that just return me to having 128GB unallocated on disk?

I guess I'm asking whether there's a `truncate`-like tool or technique for GPT.

Comment: After shrinking the partition(s): 1. Clone from the head end to the tail end of the last partition. Do it via an image file or directly to the target drive; 2. On the target drive: repair the GPT with `gdisk` or more user friendly with `gpt-fix` according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#gpt-fix). Explanation: when the size is different, the backup gpt-table must be rewritten (to the tail end of the target drive). Allow a small margin, 1 MB is more than enough, from the tail end of the last partition to the tail end of the drive.

Comment: (I don't know any single tool that can do the whole job for you, but would be happy to find one.)