# ISO for backing up linux

Tags: backup, iso

I am interested in backing and restore my linux file-sytem to an external ntfs drive in an extremely fast way, not interested in compression but needs a compression method to preserve its file permission system.

Is ISO format suitable for my purpose?

Comment: I prefer using .img files as created with **Gnome-Disks**, (which comes with Ubuntu). I usually run it from a Live USB. It also backs up the bootloader so the restored OS is bootable. Some people prefer Clonezilla. .img files can be stored on a NTFS disk. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Comment: I wish to store and sync files on iso via rsync using incremental backup system.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at **Rsync** or if you prefer a GUI, **Grsync**.

Comment: Does ISO preserve linux based file permissions?

Comment: I don't know about ISO but IMG does.

Comment: I suggest that you use [Clonezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248), which is fast and provides compression. You can create an image (a directory with several files) of a whole drive or of one or more partitions. If you want a complete image, that restores to a fully working system, I suggest that you makes an image of the whole drive.

Comment: Well I am an academician and only needs my OS to run research related packages and software so no need to back up the whole server  :). Incremental backup with rsync on an IMG disk will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have built an empty iso of around 70GB file on my ubuntu system, then converted iso to ext4 system using guide from http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/create_mountable_disk_image_gnulinux/

**I have checked and verified that the linux filesystem stored on iso based ext 4 file-system  does indeed preserve filesystem permissions and also support incremental backup from rsync when mounted via "loop" method on your linux system.**

But there is no compression, but now you have an archive file that may be carried on your **usb(any file-system)**, while cloning your system on fly.

You may also use **resize2fs** command to resize(enlarge or shrink(be careful)) according to your need while using command suggested at
["Re-size" the .img for smaller SD-card. How to SHRINK a bootable SD card image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174487/re-size-the-img-for-smaller-sd-card-how-to-shrink-a-bootable-sd-card-image).

However, ideally one must keep a static copy and a second dynamical resizable version for precaution or one can simply just use **sparse img file**.