# Cloning 16Gb USB Lubuntu drive to 16Gb Micro SD card - "no space left on device"

Tags: usb, lubuntu, dd, clone

I am trying to clone a persistent Lubuntu 16.10 installation on a 16Gb Sandisk USB memory stick to a Sandisk 16Gb Micro SD card. I did this:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=sdimage.img bs=4M
dd if=sdimage.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

Where /dev/sdb was the USB memory stick and /dev/sdc was the target Micro SD card. After several hours the job ended with:

```
dd: error writing /dev/sdc: no space left on device
3799+0 records in
3798+0 records out
15931539456 bytes (16GB, 15 GiB) copied, 10604 s, 1.5 MB/s
```

So it seems that the real capacity of the Micro SD card is smaller than that of the USB memory stick with the same nominal capacity. Can anyone recommend a way of cloning the O/S from the USB stick to the SD card which will work with the slightly "smaller" SD card?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone to a smaller harddisk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/409204/how-to-clone-to-a-smaller-harddisk)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use GParted to shrink the partitions on the `sdimage.img` file.

1. Do `sudo losetup /dev/loop0 sdimage.img`
2. `sudo gparted /dev/loop0` (Install GParted if you haven't already)
3. Edit the last partition to be slightly smaller.