# how to clone sd card without mbr with ubuntu?

Tags: sd-card, dd, clone

I clone an sd card (32Go) and I copy it to a sd card of different size (64Go).

I use those commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=Debian.img status=progress
sudo dd if=Debian.img of=/dev/sdc status=progress
```

I would like to clone my sd care without the mbr to avoid this.

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone to a smaller harddisk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409204/how-to-clone-to-a-smaller-harddisk)

Answer (score 0):

Easy with gnome-disks, works perfectly ...........................................

[image]